# What to call someone who knows How to Search for a information?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word to describe someone who knows how to search for an information in a knowledge base.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! In order to help us answer your question, it would be helpful if you gave a bit more context for how you plan to use this word. The answer to your question may depend on what type of problem this person is supposed to be trying to solve. For example, if the problem is a crime, and the person knows how to solve crimes, one possible word would be *sleuth*. But that word might not be appropriate in other contexts.

Comment: @linguisticturn My character is good at searching for information in a website. So the question is like,
One who know how to search for a solution in a knowledge base?

Comment: You may want to add this clarification to the text of the question, as well as perhaps to the title. Also, do you mean *information* or *solution*? They are not equivalent.

Comment: @linguisticturn It must be information

Comment: @Laurel Nope! I don't think so! This is just searching a website. My Character knows how to find an information in a knowledge base.

Comment: Honestly, I doubt there is an established word for this. You may have to invent one. My suggestion: *info-sleuth*.

Comment: _Researcher_ would cover it.

Answer (score 0):

Librarian

In the old days it just meant somebody who knew their way around books, but the job has grown.

I have an acquaintance who is a librarian for a large firm of solicitors, her job is finding supporting case law, judgements, comments from judges etc. wherever she can find it.

> Librarians help people find information and use it effectively for
>   personal and professional purposes. They must have knowledge of a wide
>   variety of scholarly and public information sources and must follow
>   trends related to publishing, computers, and the media to oversee the
>   selection and organization of library materials.

from here [What does a librarian do](https://studentscholarships.org/salary/373/librarians.php#sthash.C7TLqxpq.dpbs)

Comment: Actually this is simple. We got a knowledge base which contains many information. I am gonna give an award to the person who used the  Knowledge base often. I am looking for an apt word to describe the award.

Comment: @Aswanth i guess as you didn't upvote me that means you didn't like it?

Comment: Chief librarian.

Comment: I think the problem with *librarian* is that it is normally taken to be the name of a profession, and to earn it you must either work as an actual librarian or have a relevant degree. Just because someone is good at finding stuff in a knowledge base does not make them a librarian.